# A cipher that really actually isn't

Tags: word, cipher

Clue 1:

> $8^1$, $6^1$, $15^2$, $15^3$, $5^3$, $2^4$, $2^4$, $4^4$, $3^5$, $3^5$, $3^5$, $3^6$, $11^6$, $5^7$, $2^7$ 
>    $7^1$, $2^1$, $19^2$, $18^3$, $5^3$, $6^4$, $6^4$, $6^4$, $7^5$, $7^5$, $1^5$, $7^6$, $7^6$, $1^7$, $6^7$

Clue 2:

> You cannot multiply anything by zero. The answer is always zero. Thus, if you zero zero multiply zero multiply zero multiply zero multiply zero multiply zero multiply zero and you divide it into two, you get the answer.

What word am I?

Hint 1:

> You need both clues to solve the puzzle

Hint 2:

> Add the same squares together

Hint 3:

> Divide the second part into two

Hint 4:

> Write down the second statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> **STRING**

By doing:

> HINT 2: Adding the same squares together and assigning alphabets in the A1Z26 format we get "**NOTHING IS WRONG**"

Then:

> Writing down the second clue we get **00X0X0X0X0X0X0**, which has the same number of characters as **NOTHINGISWRONG**

Hence:

> Using Hint 3, classifying (dividing into 2) the letters from NOTHINGISWRONG using the positions of 0s and Xs, we get **NOHNIWOG** and **TIGSRN**. The first word is ignored because they're all zeros as per Clue 2.

Finally,

> An anagram of the second word **TIGSRN** is **STRING**

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! Congrats, that IS the correct answer! Well done!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

> NOTHING IS WRONG

which became obvious with

> Hint 2: Add the same squares together (and convert it to alphabet with A=1, B=2, ..., Z=26)

and related to the clue #2 it could be because:

> Nothing is not the same as zero, and since "The (true) answer is always zero", then the answer "NOTHING" IS WRONG

Comment: Nice! You got the first part but I'm afraid that's not the correct word. Welcome to puzzling and a great answer you got there!